# C# stream reader read line to stor in data

Tags: c#, while-loop, streamreader

I have sample.txt here:

```
ABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDE
1000 ABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDE
1001 BCDEABCDEABCDEABCDEA
1002 CDEABCDEABCDEABCDEAB
1003 DEABCDEABCDEABCDEABC
1004 EABCDEABCDEABCDEABCD
1005 AABBCCDDEEABCDEABCDE
1006 ABBCCDDEEAABCDEABCDE
1007 ACBEDADCEBBCDEAABABA
1008 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
1009 BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
1010 EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
1011 CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
1012 DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
0000
```

first line is the standard answer, the following are the student ID (4 digits) and student answers(20 digits).
and the requirement is unless student ID =0000, **else read the line to array.array[0]=student1 id,array[1]=student 1 answeer. or studentID[0]=student 1 ID, answer[0]=student 1 answer.**
I am not familiar with while condition with increasing i.

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int id;
            string line;
            string[] token;


            var lineCount = File.ReadLines("C:\\testresult\\exam.txt").Count();
            Console.WriteLine(lineCount);
            string[] record = new string[lineCount];

            try
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\testresult\\exam.txt");
                line = sr.ReadLine();

                line = sr.ReadLine();
                token = line.Split();
                id = Convert.ToInt32(token[0]);
                while (id != 0)
                {
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(token[1]);
                        line = sr.ReadLine();
                        token = line.Split();
                        id = Convert.ToInt32(token[0]);
                        for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i = i + 2)
                        {
                           record[i]=Convert.ToString(id);
                            record[i + 1] = token[1];
                            Console.WriteLine(record[i], record[i + 1]);

                        }
                    }
                }
                sr.Close();
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone advise how to read lines one by one and store the id and token[0] into each element in the array every time?

Comment: I'd recommend using a `List<string>` instead of an array so you can just add the values as you iterate the lines until you hit the 0000 line.

Comment: I always try to use File.ReadAllLines and then process the result line by line.

Comment: Can you clarify what this means "store the id and token[0] into each element" ? Is id and token[0] the same? and what is the end result you are looking for?

Comment: @TaW Allow me to point you at the documentation for [File.ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) method being used (badly) by the OP, which you can use in a similar way; but without loading the whole file into memory at once.

Comment: MSDN: _when you are working with very large files, ReadLines can be more efficient_ Let's make that _when and if_

Comment: @TaW Sure; but you did say "I *always* try to use File.ReadAllLines", so I was just trying to point out it isn't always the best solution...

Comment: Agreed. One optimizes for memory the other for speed and disk usage. I have lots of memory ;-)

Comment: I need to take student ID as one element in array and afterward is student answer, then i+2=student2 ID and student 2 answer, or student id in one array the student answer in another array

Comment: list did the job. But I am debugging to make all function work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's run through a couple of basic learning points.

1. Don't do `try...catch` unless you're going to actually do something
   with the exception.
2. StreamReader is `IDisposable` so should be in a `using` block
3. The posted code will iterate through the entire file twice. Not an issue for a small file; but I wanted to point that out.
4. Try to get into the habit of only declaring variables as close to the 'scope' that they are used in - it makes your code easier to read and maintain (e.g. when moving code around), and there is no performance hit for declaring local variables inside a loop.
5. String.Split will always give you one item (the zeroth) but you are using the 1st item `token[1]` without checking whether there is one, and there won't be when Id=0, which would give you an IndexOutOfRangeException.
6. You have a pair of matched braces for no apparent reason, which can and should be removed (keep your code simple).
7. You definitely seem confused in terms of having the `for` loop inside the `while` loop. Your `while` loop will be executed for each line in the file except the first one, so you just need to keep count of how many times you've been through the loop.
8. If you were going to make your code a bit more 'defensive' you could use int.TryParse rather than Convert.ToInt32; but I'm going to assume you're not worried about that.

So that would give you...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var records = new List<string>();
    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("C:\\testresult\\exam.txt").Skip(1))
    {
        var tokens = line.Split();
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(tokens[0]);
        if (id == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (tokens.Length > 1)
        {
            // It looks like you want the Id and values to be put consecutively in the same array, which doesn't seem very useful.
            // I would have thought a Dictionary<int,string> would be more useful... but here you go.
            records.Add(id.ToString());
            records.Add(tokens[1]);
        }
    }

    // If you really want records to be an array you can use "records.ToArray()"

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: when i tried to console.writeline(record)in the loop, it shows system.collection.generic.list`1[system.string],what is wrong??

Comment: but your advice is really very helpful and clear. I love it!!

Comment: @DavidShi Nothing's wrong. `records` is a collection of strings. When you call WriteLine on it, it is showing you the the result of ToString on the object, which is just the name of the type.

Comment: I tried to upvote, but my level is not enough to raise it.. sorry for that!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hash Table to record your data.
Ex:

```
//Record data to Hash Table   
Hashtable hash = new Hashtable();

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Binh\Desktop\C#\test\exam.txt");
    while(sr.EndOfStream == false)
    {
        string line = sr.ReadLine();

        if(!line.StartsWith("0") && !Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^[A-Z]"))
        {
            string[] info = line.Split(' ');//Split string
            string strudent_id = info[0];
            string student_ans = info[1];
            hash.Add(strudent_id, student_ans);
        }
    }
    sr.Close();

    //Watch the result
    foreach (DictionaryEntry item in hash)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "," + item.Value);
        //OUTPUT:
        //1007,ACBEDADCEBBCDEAABABA
        //1009,BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
        //1010,EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
        //1012,DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
        //1001,BCDEABCDEABCDEABCDEA
        //1002,CDEABCDEABCDEABCDEAB
        //1004,EABCDEABCDEABCDEABCD
        //1006,ABBCCDDEEAABCDEABCDE
        //1008,AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
        //1011,CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
        //1000,ABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDE
        //1003,DEABCDEABCDEABCDEABC
        //1005,AABBCCDDEEABCDEABCDE
    }
```

Ex : If you want to get answer of student with ID 1009

```
string answer = hash["1009"].ToString();
Console.WriteLine(answer);//Return BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

Comment: A strongly typed generic dictionary would be a better choice than hashtable.

Comment: StreamReader is disposable so should be in a `using` block. The specification said "first line is the standard answer", but you've implemented that with a Regex which is used against each line to potentially ignore it (does not match what was requested). Similarly, you test for StartsWith 0 rather than the specified "0000" (so if the 4 digit id is 0123, it will be ignored). Typo "strudent".

Comment: @Richardissimo I just give him an example, if he want to record standard answer he can easily archive that by adding some lines of code
 if(Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^[A-Z]"))
  {
     string standard_ans = line;
  }

About case id of student is "0000". There is no answer after that, so we can ignore it. These code below just ignore the case that id start with 0 and there is no answer also.(so if the case is 0001 and have answer it'll record properly  not ignore ).

 if(!line.StartsWith("0") && !Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^[A-Z]"))
  {
    //Do something
  }

Comment: One more thing, if there are many student,then you have a large amount of data, when you want to find answer of some students in the list, it'll take much time to search. But with hashtable ( or any type of generic dictionary is always a better choice than "List<string>" ), It's always a fast way,because it's not depend on the amount of data.

Comment: You have misunderstood my points, let me try again... "**first line** is the standard answer", not just any line matching a Regex: what if the next exams answers are numeric?. Regarding "0000" : again you misunderstood my point: I was highlighting that your code decided that any line starting with "0" matches that criteria, not just one which starts with "0000" , so although you *say* it will record 0001, it won't. Regarding Slow search: I completely agree, and said so in my own answer, but the OP specified very clearly what they wanted was a 1 dimensional sequence of values. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, you're right "if(!line.StartsWith("0") && !Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^[A-Z]"))" This code will ignore id 0001.But there is just an exmaple and he can completely modify this code based on his situation. About "first line is the standard answer" .There is many ways to get that info. Ex: File.ReadAllLines() to read file and get first object in array (first line). Or he can also use StreamReader to get first line = standard answer first before run loop to read all regarding lines in file.

Comment: Finally,the thing that I want to mention is this is an example code, he could refer and modify based on his situation.

Comment: People come to StackOverflow to get answers to their questions, not to get answers which don't do what has clearly been stated in the question so that they have to fix it themselves. I rest my case.